# Why struct shallow copy does not work?

Tags: c, struct

I'm testing shallow copy for struct with this code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

int main() {

    struct str {
        char * name;
        int value;
    };

    struct str str_1 = {"go", 255};
    struct str str_2;

    str_2 = str_1;

    str_1.name = "back";

    printf("%s\n",str_1.name);
    printf("%s\n",str_2.name);

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the result should be:

```
back 
back
```

But it was:

```
back
go
```

**Edit:** I expected that because with shallow copy, `str_1.name` and `str_2.name` should always point to same place.

**Edit:** And with dynamic allocation, I got what I expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    struct str {
        char * name;
        int value;
    };

    struct str str_1; 
    struct str str_2;

    str_1.name = (char*) malloc(5);
    strcpy(str_1.name,"go");

    str_2 = str_1;

    strcpy(str_1.name,"back");

    printf("%s\n",str_1.name);
    printf("%s\n",str_2.name);

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
back 
back
```

**What was I misunderstand here ?**

Comment: I don't know. Why did you expect what you expected? That's not what "shallow" means...

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question IMHO. A degree of "obviousness" should not attract downvotes. General Relativity is obvious to some folk.

Comment: @Bathsheba: True, but the lack of describing expectations attracts downvotes. It's hard to explain why the world doesn't conform to a hidden expectation.

Comment: The problem is with your use of "always". *After the copy*, the two pointers are equal (and thus point to the same thing). But you can then *change* one of the pointers so it points somewhere else. Just like `int a = 5, b; b = a;` is a shallow copy of the value 5, but you can still say `b = 7;` later. The "shallow" refers to the thing that's pointed to. By contrast, a deep copy would copy the string allocation, and then give the copied struct the pointer to the copied allocation. In other words, a shallow copy copies `p`, and a deep copy copies `*p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a piece of paper and draw what you think is happening at each step slowly, and this should become clear.

Let's draw `struct str` as so:

```
---------------------
| const char * name |
---------------------
| int value         |
---------------------
```

And let's denote a string at address `0xabcdef10` as so:

```
--0xabcdef10---------------------
|  "string\0"                   |
---------------------------------
```

So, when we initialise `str_1`, we need some memory location which will hold "go", lets call that `0xaaaaaa00`

```
--0xaaaaaa00---------------------
|  "go\0"                       |
---------------------------------
```

Then we initialise `str_1` with a pointer to that:

```
struct str str_1 = {"go", 255};

--str_1---------------------------
| const char * name = 0xaaaaaa00 |
----------------------------------
| int value = 255                |
----------------------------------
```

Now we take a shallow copy of `str_1`, and call it `str_2`:

```
--str_2---------------------------
| const char * name = 0xaaaaaa00 |
----------------------------------
| int value = 255                |
----------------------------------
```

Next we execute     `str_1.name = "back";`. As before, we first want to create the new string. Lets put that at `0xbbbbbb00`:

```
--0xbbbbbb00---------------------
|  "back\0"                     |
---------------------------------
```

Then we assign it to `str_1.name`, so `str_1` now looks like:

```
--str_1---------------------------
| const char * name = 0xbbbbbb00 |
----------------------------------
| int value = 255                |
----------------------------------
```

Note that we haven't changed `str_2`.

So, when we look at our final "memory", we see:

```
--0xaaaaaa00---------------------
|  "go\0"                       |
---------------------------------
  ....

--0xbbbbbb00---------------------
|  "back\0"                     |
---------------------------------
  ....
--str_1---------------------------
| const char * name = 0xbbbbbb00 |
----------------------------------
| int value = 255                |
--str_2---------------------------
| const char * name = 0xaaaaaa00 |
----------------------------------
| int value = 255                |
----------------------------------
```

So str_1 points at the new string, and str_2 points at the old string.

In case you describe as dynamic, you never update the pointers in the struct, you could go through the same exercise to draw out what happens to memory in that case.

Answer (score 2):

`str_2 = str_1;` *did* take a shallow copy.

But that *doesn't* mean that that any subsequent alteration to what `name` points to in `str_1` will be automatically reflected in `str_2`.

(Really you should use `const char*` as the string type as you are assigning read-only string *literals*).

Comment: I've edited the question with dynamic allocation case, could you please show me more in your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

`str_2 = str_1;` makes a hard copy of the struct itself. For example the `value` member will be unique for every struct.

But you got a soft copy of any pointer members, since the copy does not affect the pointed-at data of any pointer. Meaning that after the copy, the `name` pointer of both `str_1` and `str_2` points at the literal `"go"`.

And then `str_1.name = "back";` only changes where `str_1.name` points at. It doesn't change where `str_2.name` points at.

When you used malloc and strcpy, you change the pointed-at data and get a complete hard copy of everything.